# Can't insert data into Mongodb in Laravel

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5, mongodb-query, jenssegers-mongodb

Let me explain all the step that I followed. I am using LAMP.

First of all I installed Laravel , MongoDB and jenssegers/laravel-mongodb pakage. For this I followed [this link](http://haafiz.me/development/using-laravel-with-mongodb).

After that I create database, table and insert data using terminal with all success.

Next step is to integrate mongodb with laravel so I add MongoDB connection detail in **app/config/database.php** file.

```
'mongodb' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'usedgoodstore'),
    ],

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mongodb'),
```

Up to this point all work fine.

Next I create route, view, controller, model file and insert code.

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::post('/index', 'UserController@index');
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ url('/index') }}" method="post">
                <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
                First name:<br>
                <input type="text" name="firstname">
                <br>
                Last name:<br>
                <input type="text" name="lastname">
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

**UserController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Model\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController  extends Controller{

protected $user;

public  function __construct(User $user){
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function Index(Request $request){

    $data = array('firstname' => $request['firstname'], 'lastname' => $request['lastname']);

    $user = $this->user->PostUser($data);

    return response()->json($user,200);

}


}
```

**User.php (model file)**

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Moloquent;

use DB; // if I use and not use this statement and then getting different errors

class User extends Moloquent {

protected $connection = 'mongodb';

protected $collection = 'user';


public function PostUser($data){


   

        $insertData = DB::collection('user')->insert($data); // I'm getting error on this line.
    if($insertData){
        return true;
    }

}

}
```

**Error I'm getting is :**

> FatalThrowableError in User.php line 25:
> Class 'App\Model\DB' not found

If I add **use db** in **User.php (model file)** I'm getting below error.

> FatalThrowableError in DatabaseManager.php line 317:
> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::collection()

What have I missed?

Comment: Do you found an answer ?

Comment: @hotips yes I found answer

Answer (score 2):

First open app/config/database.php file and make your mongodb default database.

> 'default' => 'mongodb',

and if you don't want mongodb as a default database connection then you can do following thing.

```
public function PostUser($data){
    $insertData = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('user')->insert($data); // I'm getting error on this line.
if($insertData){
    return true;
}
```